# How to direct authenticated and anonymous users to different ( custom ) front pages?

Tags: redirection

I want anonymous users to always see `/node/1` but authenticated users to see `/myview/uid` where uid is the current user's id.

I don't want to use [**Rules**](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but would prefer a code solution.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you not want to use Rules? either way you will be adding a new module to the pile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_user_login function to achieve this.

```
function custom_module_user_login(&$edit, $account){
  if($acount->uid > 0) {
          $redirection = 'myview/'.$acount->uid;  
  } else{
      $redirection = 'node/1';
  }

  // Unless there is already a redirection going, or the user is trying to reset his password, we redirect to $redirection.

  if (!is_null($redirection) && (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset')){
    $_GET['destination'] = $redirection; // Should we use $edit['redirect'] instead..?
    $GLOBALS['destination'] = $redirection; // Should we use $edit['redirect'] instead..?
  }
```

}

For more info [check here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7)

Comment: since this only runs on a user logging in, how does it address the anonymous aspect of the question?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted anonymous users to always see the login page which happens to be the front page and authenticated users to be redirected to `/dashboard`. My solution is thus:

1. Create theme template file `page--front.tpl.php` ( You should aready have `page.tpl.php`).
2. Add the following code to the top of the page:

   ```
   if($logged_in){
       drupal_goto('dashboard');
   }
   ```

In your case you can just add the following code on the top of `page.tpl.php` and it should work just fine.

```
if($logged_in && request_path() != 'myview/uid'){
    drupal_goto('myview/uid');
}
if(!$logged_in && request_path() != 'node/1'){
    drupal_goto('node/1');
}
```

This will redirect all authenticated users to `/myview/uid` and all anonymous users to `node/1`